# inspectdb command crashes when generate model classes from postgres db

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

when executing inspectdb > modelys.py , i'm getting the following error.
I searched for solution but i cant find anything. More over i dont know what this error really mean.

```
(gathiApiVirtualEnv) G:\GathiCatalog\dev\gathiApi\gathi_api>python manage.py inspectdb >models.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "G:\GathiCatalog\dev\gathiApi\gathiApiVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "G:\GathiCatalog\dev\gathiApi\gathiApiVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "G:\GathiCatalog\dev\gathiApi\gathiApiVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "G:\GathiCatalog\dev\gathiApi\gathiApiVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "G:\GathiCatalog\dev\gathiApi\gathiApiVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\inspectdb.py", line 28, in handle
    for line in self.handle_inspection(options):
  File "G:\GathiCatalog\dev\gathiApi\gathiApiVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\inspectdb.py", line 163, in handle_inspection
    for meta_line in self.get_meta(table_name, constraints, column_to_field_name):
  File "G:\GathiCatalog\dev\gathiApi\gathiApiVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\inspectdb.py", line 273, in get_meta
    tup = '(' + ', '.join("'%s'" % column_to_field_name[c] for c in columns) + ')'
  File "G:\GathiCatalog\dev\gathiApi\gathiApiVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\inspectdb.py", line 273, in <genexpr>
    tup = '(' + ', '.join("'%s'" % column_to_field_name[c] for c in columns) + ')'
KeyError: 'prj_id'
```

Comment: what version of django are you using?

Comment: Django Version : 2.0.3

Comment: Ensure that the user you're using to inspect the DB has appropriate permissions to all tables. Try supplying each table name manually to `inspectdb` and see if this problem happens on all of the tables or just one.

Comment: I inspected on each table and i get an error on particular table but that table does not have any field prj_id.